# SQL server – get rows with customers that has only purchased online

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table (TransactionData) containing transaction data for customers and one table (Subscribers) containing customers that are newsletter subscribers. This is what I need to do.

Select all subscribers from TransactionData table that are also in the Subscribers table and that has only purchased products online (StoreID = 50001).

The unique key for both tables is the customer email address.

This is the basic table structure.

```
TransactionData
Email               StoreID OrderID
customer1@mail.com  50001   101
customer1@mail.com  50001   102
customer2@mail.com  50001   201
customer2@mail.com  51111   202
customer3@mail.com  50001   301
customer3@mail.com  50001   302


Subscribers
Email
customer1@mail.com
customer2@mail.com


Desired result
Email               StoreID
customer1@mail.com  50001
```

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT b.Email, b.StoreID
FROM TransactionData AS a
INNER JOIN Subscribers AS b
ON a.Email = b.Email
WHERE a.BoutiqueId = 50001
```

I can’t figure out how to exclude customers that have purchased both online and in store. Can you help me with this?

Comment: how do you decide if a purchase was made online?

Comment: You are selecting the StoreID from the Subscribers table, but in your 'basic table structure' there is no StoreID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t.Email , t.StoreID 
FROM TransactionData t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM Subscribers 
              WHERE t.Email = Email)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                FROM TransactionData
                WHERE t.Email = Email
                 AND StoreID <> 50001)
GROUP BY t.Email , t.StoreID
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you tell me how to do the other way around? If I want to exclude all of those that have purchased online (50001) from TransactionData?

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @TransactionData TABLE 
    ([Email] varchar(18), [StoreID] int, [OrderID] int)
;

INSERT INTO @TransactionData
    ([Email], [StoreID], [OrderID])
VALUES
    ('customer1@mail.com', 50001, 101),
    ('customer1@mail.com', 50001, 102),
    ('customer2@mail.com', 50001, 201),
    ('customer2@mail.com', 51111, 202),
    ('customer3@mail.com', 50001, 301),
    ('customer3@mail.com', 50001, 302)
;


declare @Subscribers  TABLE
    ([Email] varchar(18))
;

INSERT INTO @Subscribers
    ([Email])
VALUES
    ('customer1@mail.com'),
    ('customer2@mail.com')
;

select T.Email,T.StoreID from @TransactionData T
INNER JOIN @Subscribers TT
ON TT.Email = T.Email
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                FROM @TransactionData
                WHERE t.Email = Email
                 AND StoreID <> 50001)
GROUP BY T.Email,T.StoreID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `except` which returns the customers who only made a purchase online (botiqueid = 50001)

```
SELECT b.Email, b.StoreID
FROM TransactionData AS a
INNER JOIN Subscribers AS b
ON a.Email = b.Email
WHERE a.BoutiqueId = 50001
EXCEPT
SELECT b.Email, b.StoreID
FROM TransactionData AS a
INNER JOIN Subscribers AS b
ON a.Email = b.Email
WHERE a.BoutiqueId <> 50001
```

Comment: @jarlh..sure..for a faster query response.

Comment: `except`and `intersect` doesn't have any `all` modifier, only `union` does.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT
 EMail, MIN(StoreID) AS StoreID
FROM TransactionData
GROUP BY EMail HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN StoreID = 50001 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Well here's what I did.

Keep your "valid" data in a temp table which has been inner joined from TransactionData with Subscribers table.

```
SELECT
    a.Email
    , a.OrderID
    , a.StoreID
INTO #tmpValidCustomers
FROM TransactionData AS a
INNER JOIN Subscribers AS b
ON 
    a.Email = b.Email
```

right, this should be the result

[image]

then, use this temp table to validate from itself. I created 2 types of column, one column from which you identify that this email bought in your online store, and one column which which you identify that this email bought NOT from your online store.

```
SELECT
        Email
        , OrderID
        , StoreID
        , (SELECT TOP 1 OrderID FROM #tmpValidCustomers WHERE Email = v.Email and StoreID = 50001) AS [Cond1]
        , (SELECT TOP 1 OrderID FROM #tmpValidCustomers WHERE Email = v.Email and StoreID <> 50001) AS [Cond2]
    FROM #tmpValidCustomers v
```

and this should be the result

[image]

now, whats left is to filter all distinct email ID's which who only bought in your online store. Execute an outer select from the table above.

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT
        Email
        , StoreID
FROM (
    SELECT
        Email
        , OrderID
        , StoreID
        , (SELECT TOP 1 OrderID FROM #tmpValidCustomers WHERE Email = v.Email and StoreID = 50001) AS [Cond1]
        , (SELECT TOP 1 OrderID FROM #tmpValidCustomers WHERE Email = v.Email and StoreID <> 50001) AS [Cond2]
    FROM #tmpValidCustomers v
) AS T
WHERE
    T.Cond1 IS NOT NULL AND T.Cond2 IS NULL
```

EDIT : My apologies, it can be done this way alone.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.Email
    , a.StoreID
FROM TransactionData AS a
INNER JOIN Subscribers AS b
ON 
    a.Email = b.Email
WHERE
    a.Email NOT IN (SELECT Email FROM #TransactionData WHERE StoreID <> 50001)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
SELECT 
    a.Email, a.StoreID
FROM
    TransactionData AS a
        INNER JOIN
    Subscribers AS b ON a.Email = b.Email
WHERE
    a.StoreID = 50001
GROUP BY a.Email
```

Comment: Wow this was my first post ever, I will try all of your suggestions! Thank you!! :)

Comment: @SatenderK The query won't produce the desired result so the down vote is justified. Either correct it or delete the answer if you want to get rid of the down vote (which was mine, not Marinas).